# Ligatures in figures and pdftex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, ligatures

In the following example, the 'ff' ligature in the figure labels (in 'differential') disappears when `pdflatex` is used, but the fault does not occur if `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` is used instead. Both `lualatex` and `xelatex` produce the correct results, using the pdf version of the figure. Is there a problem with the figure, or is this a bug in `pdftex`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Cluster2}
\end{document}
```

[Cluster2.pdf](http://www-staff.lboro.ac.uk/~mait/pdfs/Cluster2.pdf)
[Cluster2.eps](http://www-staff.lboro.ac.uk/~mait/pdfs/Cluster2.eps)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`

From page 32 of the [pdftex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf):

> `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts` (integer)
>
> If positive, this parameter forces pdfTEX to include fonts
>   from a pdf file loaded with `\pdfximage`, even
>   if those fonts are available on disk. Bigger files might be created,
>   but included pdf files are sure to be embedded with the adequate
>   fonts; indeed, the fonts on disk might be different from the embedded
>   ones, and glyphs might be missing.

Comment: Thanks. I added the relevant quote from the pdftex manual to your answer before accepting, as it gives a perfect description of what's going on.

Comment: If I put `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in the header or in the `\includegraphics` block, it doesn't work. Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer --- He has put the comment is in the wrong place. There is a [new question on a similar subject](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306588/2417), which is where it actually belongs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I had the same symptoms as the OP, but the solution didn't changed much. How else would you define it? If there's more information I can provide, I'd be more then happy to.