# Embedding fonts in an image

Tags: fonts, pdftex, embedding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ligatures in figures and pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex)

I have a PDF image file, which has been included in my document with

```
\includegraphics{thefile.pdf}
```

The PDF has a Type 1 font embedded in it. I want to use `pdflatex` to compile, instead of `tex` -> `dvi` -> `ps` -> `pdf`, but doing so does not embed the image file fonts in the PDF.

How can I embed the Type 1 fonts in my PDF  using `pdflatex`?

Comment: The font of the included PDF image is not embedded into the document PDF, right? I guess it is still in the internal PDF. AFAIK (correct me when I'm wrong) the PDF image is included has a whole and not changed. So there should be no issue here, because all fonts are available. But I could be wrong.

Comment: So the fonts are (apparently) not embedded in the image files. When I send the document to the publisher at least, their system cannot identify the fonts internal to the figure.

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/) help?

Comment: Yep. That's what I needed.