# some greek letters disappear from PDFs included with includegraphics

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdftex, greek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ligatures in figures and pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex)

I have created some graphs in PDF format with PyX that include some labels with greek letters. When these graphs are included with \includegraphics, some letters disappear from the graphs in file produced by pdflatex. This only happens when the PyX-created file uses mathptmx (or maybe some other font-specific packages).

I made a very minimal example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{tbox}
\caption{Should see $\delta = \tau$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure tbox.pdf is created with the following python script (and PyX v0.11.1)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyx import *

text.set(mode="latex")
text.preamble(r"\usepackage{mathptmx}")

cd = canvas.canvas()
tbox = text.text(0, 0, r"$\delta = \tau$",[text.halign.boxleft])
cd.insert(tbox)
cd.writePDFfile('tbox.pdf')
```

The version of tbox.pdf as produced by python and PyX is available: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/VjH3mAF8pW/

Comment: Hi Greg, welcome to TeX.sx! You'll have to upload the file to an external file hoster (like http://www.wikiupload.com/) and edit your question to include a link to that.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2417) help at all?

Comment: `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` as suggested by Ian should work. But it is a bit unclear why you get the problem. Does PyX use another TeX-system than yourself?

Comment: I don't see a way to comment, just to add an answer, but adding \pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1 to the preamble of my document (as suggested by Ian and Ulrike above) does fix the problem. I looked through some of the source code for PyX and found that it uses LaTeX to generate a dvi file, but then it writes its own PDF. (Neither pdflatex or dvipdf are ever called.) It embeds fonts into the PDF, and it gets the font information from /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map, which I think should match the pdflatex in /usr/local/texlive/2012 which I am using on the LaTeX file

Comment: @Ulrike the sample file contained two embedded fonts -- CMR10 (sic) and "StandardSymL" -- i would guess the standardsyml is the one giving the problem.  the *copyfonts* solution sounds the way forward.

Comment: @wasteofspace Yes, it's the \delta from the StandardSymL font that goes missing. A previous workaround I had been using was to insert a white (to be invisible) \Delta somewhere. For whatever reason, if the pdf has both \Delta and \delta, they both show up, but a \delta by itself disappears.

Comment: @wasteofspace: Yes the StandardSymL font is the problem, cmr is only in the document because of the text, the equal sign and the page number. But the question is why the symbol font used by the picture is different for the one in the text. If I generate such a picture with pdftex or latex and include it then the font used in both parts is the same usyr.pfb and I don't get any problems.