# Fonts look different compiled by latex vs. pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Why is my document pdf generated by pdflatex looks different from the one generated by latex+dvips+ps2pdf ? From the code below, i have tow different papers switch to the tow cited commands above :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{M ROUAN SERIK}
\title{Article with \LaTeXe}
\fontfamily{cmr}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Titled section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here's my pdffonts for the tow pdfs :
Pdflatex:

```
name                   type     encoding  emb sub uni object ID  
------------------------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------  
AMTRHA+SFRM1728        Type 1    Custom   yes yes no       4  0  
DPTCLU+SFRM1200        Type 1    Custom   yes yes no       5  0  
JVZRKA+CMMI12          Type 1    Builtin  yes yes no       6  0  
UEWNID+SFBX1440        Type 1    Custom   yes yes no       7  0  
FOVERL+SFRM1000        Type 1    Custom   yes yes no       8  0
```

latex+dvips+ps2pdf

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID  
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------  
WVMUEH+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no        16  0  
ZHRBNN+SFBX1440                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      14  0  
IMJWCD+CMMI12                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      12  0  
MDMSVR+SFRM1200                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      10  0  
TWHNMT+SFRM1728                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       8  0
```

Comment: Select the code and press Ctrl+k to format as a code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I see no difference. Can you be more specific about what you find?

Comment: When compiling with pdflatex and with latex+dvips+ps2pdf the tow documents are different !

Comment: If you compile the document i made with pdflatex and i do, we'll don't have the same result (quality of the pdf output) mine will be such with less contrast. I think that i have a problem with the updmap or something like that.

Comment: @MehdiRouanSerik Aren't you simply getting bitmap fonts in one of them? Try to zoom in and see if the letters aren't pixelated.

Comment: I thought so. But it does'nt pixelize !

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55098/embedding-type-1c-fonts-using-lualatex.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136574/merging-duplicate-embedded-fonts/138726#138726

Comment: Answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex/337122#337122).

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** The `latex` method via `ps2pdf` embeds Type 1C (compressed) fonts, while `pdftex` embed Type 1 (the same, but not compressed). This doesn't answer why they would look different on your system; thus I would guess it is some feature of your particular setup (and therefore "too localized").

---

Apparently the `pdftex` engine by default embeds Type 1 fonts, while `ps2pdf` by default (at least in the `latex`->`dvips` toolchain) embeds Type 1C. That is the fundamental difference between your two files.

@egreg tells me that Type 1C is just a compacted version of Type 1, so it seems unlikely the PDF viewer would render it any differently. On an up-to-date TeXLive system, the two methods of producing this PDF file should look the same.

Here's the output of `pdffonts` for the file compiled with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
KWSWPX+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           yes yes no      16  0
OPEHBW+SFBX1440                      Type 1C           yes yes no      14  0
EWKLCD+CMMI12                        Type 1C           yes yes no      12  0
QLBMBF+SFRM1200                      Type 1C           yes yes no      10  0
HVWRQD+SFRM1728                      Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
```

Here's the output from the file compiled with `pdflatex`:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
AMTRHA+SFRM1728                      Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
GSTIVC+SFRM1200                      Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
JVZRKA+CMMI12                        Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
UEWNID+SFBX1440                      Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
FOVERL+SFRM1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
```

(By the way, you don't need `\fontfamily{cmr}` since that's the default. But you might consider `\usepackage{lmodern}` instead.)

Comment: Thnks, but the problem is that i can't get the same result with both commands not you !

Comment: @MehdiRouanSerik, different process to create a PDF could result in different files. No problem with this. Different ways to mix ingredients could produce different cakes (even both still are choco cakes).

Comment: I have the same result as you except for the encoding !

Comment: Sorry i'am novice at stack, i should edit my questions i did'nt know this.

Comment: As far as I know, the difference between Type 1 and Type 1C (where C stands for CFF, Compact Font Format) is just that the latter type is a compacted version of the former, taking less space.

Comment: @egreg That would explain why I don't see any difference in the files. In the OP's setup, though, might different readers render these fonts differently?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I don't think so.

Comment: If i compile with xelatex i have a PDF like the one compiled with latex+dvips+ps2pdf not the pdflatex ?

Comment: @MehdiRouanSerik Without knowing more I guess I would suggest that you just use `pdflatex` or `xelatex` unless there is some special reason to use `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf`.

Comment: +1 for this answer, and (cc @egreg) even though Type 1C is just a compacted version of Type 1, (some) PDF viewers render(ed) them differently. (As I found out [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex/337122#337122).)