# pdflatex: Handling of fonts when including other pdfs

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

I was curious about one fact: How will pdflatex deal with fonts embedded in pdfs it includes?

For example: When I include 100 pdf-files (e.g. using `\includegraphics`) will the generated output file contain the embedded fonts a hundred times (one complete set for each file included)?

Or is it smart enough to recognize that it already has the requested fonts and allow therefore file size reduction?

Comment: It is smart enough but sometimes this can lead to problem. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex/50834#50834 and other answers about `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is smart enough but sometimes this can lead to problem. See e.g. [Ligatures in figures and pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex/50834#50834) and other answers about `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts`