# "Could not parse ligature component "xxx" of "xxx_alt" in parseCharName" warning with Forest and Externalize

Tags: symbols, tikz-external, forest

I am using a few symbols from the `fontawsome` package to decorate tree generated with forest with tikz externalize. When I compile my tex document I see the following output:

```
  Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "fonttest".tex

Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "horizontal" of "ellipsis_horizontal" in parseCharName Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "folder" of "folder_open_alt" in parseCharName Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "open" of "folder_open_alt" in parseCharName Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "alt" of "folder_open_alt" in parseCharName

Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "444" of "_444" in parseCharName Syntax Warning: Could not parse ligature component "547" of "_547" in parseCharName

Process exited normally
```

When I do not externalize the warning is gone.

Not sure how should I handle this. The pdf looks ok, but not sure how it will be handled on other computers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage[edges,external]{forest}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=external-figures/] %if this is removed  Could not parse ligature component warning is gone

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  namespace/.append style={content=\textbf{\{\}} ##1},
  assembly/.append style={content=\faCogs \enskip \textbf{##1}},
  class/.append style={content=\faObjectGroup \enskip ##1}, %\faClone
  delegate/.append style={content=\faPaperPlaneO \enskip ##1},
  enum/.append style={content=\faEllipsisH \enskip ##1},
  interface/.append style={content=$\multimap$ ##1},
  fldr/.append style={content=\faFolderOpenO \enskip ##1},
  root/.append style={content=\textbf{##1}}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
for tree = {folder,grow'=0,fit=band,font=\scriptsize,inner ysep=1pt}
[ {Legend}, root
    [ {Assembly}, assembly
        [ {Namespace}, namespace
            [ {Class}, class ]
            [ {Interface}, interface ]
            [ {Enum}, enum ]
            [ {Delegate}, delegate ]
            [ {Folder}, fldr ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128513/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, It solves the described issue, but I have noticed the following: If I produce a figure with externalize and then attach it manually in a different document using includegraphics the warning is back.

Comment: Sure. You need `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in the other document too (you get the warning in this document as the tree is inserted with \includegraphics when you use externalize).