# How are fonts included from included PDFs? (avoid redundancy in fonts)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, includegraphics, file-size, pdf-a

I'm currently writing a larger LaTeX document with many included PDF files that are primarily generated from two sources: IPE and GNUPLOT.

IPE outputs .pdf directly.

GNUPLOT outsputs .tex and .eps that I combine separately as PDF (to not regenerate them every time I typeset my document)

In both workflows I use libertine as font and the resulting .pdf files are then all included in one main document, e.g., main.tex.

Questions:

1) Even a simple plot from GNUPLOT appears as relatively large to me with this approach, i.e., I suppose that the fonts are embedded in EACH file on its own?

2) If so, what happens when including the PDF in the main document? Does pdflatex 'magically' recognize that the same fonts are included such that the file size of the main document does not increase by the same amount of the included file, but instead, by the amount of the included file minus the size of the font which (if it is the same) is already included in the main document?

3) Can I somehow optimize this behavior from within pdflatex without using external tools such as pdfsizeopt?

Comment: Although I find the question interesting, is it really a practical problem if the fonts would be included multiple times? Even with hundreds of included files the size would probably still be manageable with current processing/storage/networking technologies.

Comment: To 1) the size of a vectorized output with gnuplot depends mainly on the `samples` size, and maybe the `isosample` size depending on usage. Sadly, gnuplot doesn't create nice splines or Bezier curves for vector graphics!

Comment: Acrobat will list all the fonts used under File->Properties->Fonts so you can check for duplicates.  It also has a Documents->Reduce File Size option, but I have no idea what that does.

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114402/pdflatex-handling-of-fonts-when-including-other-pdfs this should not be an issue.