# pdf figure missing text elements in beamer presentation

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a beamer presentation that I am typesetting using pdflatex in TeXworks (version 0.4.5 r.1280) on a Mac.  The page that's giving me trouble is:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Loch Ness Monster Histogram}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{nessie.pdf}
\end{figure}
}
```

When I typeset it using pdflatex, the title, notes, and axis labels disappear, even though they are part of the original pdf figure when I open it up in Preview. Just to be clear, these are part of the original pdf file, rather than specified in the beamer.

Here's the original graph:
[image]

Here's what it looks like in Beamer:
[image]

You can get the eps and pdf versions of the figure [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9d8exihb6t2xtud/nrP1Sihuft).

Comment: Can you post a picture of `nessie.pdf` and then the frame in question?  I ask because `includegraphics` wont crop the picture unless you tell it to.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2417) help?

Comment: Adding `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in the preamble does not seem to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you include the figure in an ordinary (i.e. non-Beamer) `LaTeX` document? Did the figure start life as an `eps` file? Can you make the figure (ideally the `eps` version if it exists) available for download? (Sorry to bombard you with questions!)

Comment: If I use an article, I have the same issue. The figure is is saved from a statistics package called Stata as an eps file and then converted into pdf.

Comment: Can you try with Adobe Reader?

Comment: I added a link to the eps and pdf versions of the figures.

Comment: I don't have Acrobat on my Linux machine where the figure is generated. This approach used to work until I re-imaged my hard drive and re-installed TeXworks. Everything else has remained constant.

Comment: I have had a look at the PDF version of your image: It contains Text in Helvetica, but the font is not embedded (nor subsampled). I guess that is the root of the problem. Export it in a way that the fonts get embedded. Alternatively, you may use ghostscript to embed them by converting to PS and than back to PDF with the prepress setting: `pdf2ps nessie.pdf` and then `ps2pdf13 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress nessie.ps nessie-embedded.pdf`

Comment: I see no problems with my system (Win 7, updated MikTeX 2.9 and SumatraPDF) Can you also include your preamble such that it is a complete file to compile?

Comment: @Daniel Modifying the user-written graphexportpdf script in Stata with that option seems to have fixed the problem. If you want to write that up as an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PDF image contains text in Helvetica, but the font has not been embedded:

```
~/Downloads$ pdffonts nessie.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica                            Type 1            Custom           no  no  no       8  0
```

Even though *Helvetica* should be a PDF standard font, I have often experienced problems with PDF images that do not embedd all uses glyphs. Hence, you should export it in a way that font (subsets) get embedded.

If the respective fonts are installed on your system in a way that ghostscript can find them (which should be the case for all standard PS fonts), you may also use ghostscript to convert your PDF to PS and then to PDF with the `prepress` setting, resulting in a version that embeds the used glyphs:

```
~/Downloads$ pdf2ps nessie.pdf
~/Downloads$ ps2pdf13 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress nessie.ps nessie2.pdf
    ~/Downloads$ pdffonts nessie2.pdf
    name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
    ------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
    EKNWHA+Helvetica                     Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  0
```