# \includegraphics of PDF figures

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a figure in PDF format generated by R including 2 axes with label and markers. I want to include the figure in LaTeX document. When using `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{fig.pdf}`, the plot is included but the labels and markers on the axes in the PDF file are lost.

What happened? What can I do?

[image]
[image: The figure on page 70 is the result of pdfLaTex. But the original figure in pdf has other parts in it.]

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{figSvsS.pdf} 
\end{center}
\caption{Estimated Difference Profile: Shakespeare vs. Shakespeare} \label{fig2:authorship1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: No idea without seeing the image and your latex file.  Does everything show up as you'd want if you're viewing the pdf file in pdf viewers?

Comment: I bet @JPi meant the image that is not working, not a screenshot of the result. Still no LaTeX code posted as well.

Comment: Potential duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129309/24974

Comment: Also please do not use the center env to center the image. Both figure and center adds vertical space around the image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear since there was no feedback by the OP that could lead to solving the mystery. Also, be aware that using a `center` environment is pointless in a `figure`. Use `\centering` iinstead.