# pdflatex \includegraphics changes the font

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdf, eps, embedding

I've a EPS figure file (and the same as a PDF after "ps2pdf -dEPSCrop") created from a Matlab figure. It contains some text annotations, including a Greek delta ($\Delta$). In GhostView this EPS figure, and the PDF figure, look as expected.

That is, on its own the Figure looks fine. However, when the figure (PDF/EPS) is included with includegraphics the Greek 'delta' in the Figure gets corrupted into what looks like a Danish 'o'. Any suggestions?

Update: A MWE is below. A copy of the PDF Figure (about 4 kB) is at https://user.iter.org/filesharing/?uid=f54e3cdc-a0f8-42f2-a1d6-66bbfb26d71f

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
The figure is loaded with includegraphics of a PDF file that contains a plot and some text, including the greek $\Delta$.
\begin{figure}[t!]
\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,angle=0]{pdf-mathmode-greek-Figure.pdf}
\caption{Testing \textDelta{} and math $\Delta$ in the caption.}
\label{fig:AxV}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's very hard to help you without the pdf which creates the problem. Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2417) help?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I've uploaded a copy of the PDF figure that contains the greek Delta. After pdflatexing the updated MWE given above, the Delta still gets corrupted. The Delta's in the tex itself display fine...

Comment: I do not have any issues with the MWE, the `\Delta` looks fine both in Evince and Adobe Reader

Comment: Ah! For some reason I didn't check the pdflatex output PDF in Adobe Reader -- you are right, it looks fine there! I guess that solves the problem. Only in the TeXworks viewer it is corrupt. Thanks for the check!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a viewer issue, solved in the comments.

Comment: I have also reproduced a similar BUG. It seems I have font discoloration to grey because of an embedded PDF using includegraphics. The bug is visible in Preview and TexShop, but not in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: This is most probably related to MiKTeX installation "for all users" (see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/339), and/or not installed some of font packages containing Ghostscript's free fonts, probably `symbol` (see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112).

I think the question is related to distributions and should be opened again.

Comment: `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` probably did not embed Symbol font. Check these: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512562/115879, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502252/115879.