# Loss of greek symbols in epstopdf conversion

Tags: greek, epstopdf, embedding

When inserting Matlab figures I use the standard approach of saving the figure as a '.eps' file and using the 'epstopdf' conversion package in the preamble. My figure contains the Greek letter mu in the x-label and is recognisable as mu in both the .eps file and the .pdf figure created by the epstopdf package. However, the symbol changes to an infinity symbol when the graph is included in the compiled report. Weirdly I have used the symbol phi in the legend of a previous graph using the same approach and had no problems. All legends and labels in the original .eps files are in Times New Roman. Any ideas what could be happening?

Update - here are the graphs:

Update 2: Graphs removed. I haven't figured out how to upload the eps file yet, but I found out something significant. The corrupt mu symbol is only corrupt in the TeXworks view of the pdf, when I open the pdf in Adobe all the greek symbols are intact. There must be a bug in my TeXworks version.

This link discusses the same problem:
[pdflatex \includegraphics changes the font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144969/pdflatex-includegraphics-changes-the-font)

Comment: (1) Welcome. (2) Not everyone here is using MatLab, would is be possible to see that EPS file? Perhaps you can upload it somewhere and post a link to it.

Comment: Hello daleif. I can upload the .eps file from work tomorrow if it will help. Once the .eps file is created and the .pdf figure is created from that file I assumed that anything I had done in Matlab previously would be irrelevant as far as Latex was concerned. The problem doesn't exist in any of the source files, only in the Latex compiled report.

Comment: My first guess is that the greek font isn't embedded in the eps file.  but i'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: Mike, it looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @Mike, we of course cannot do anything with those, we need the real EPS files. As Mike Renfro remarks below, it may simply be bad fonts. But we need the EPS.

Comment: @Mike please refer to the comment above about merging accounts.

Comment: When saving an EPS figure in MatLab use use the command "interpreter"
for example: xlabel('Wavelength $${\mum}$$','Interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 12)

Answer (score 2):

In general, fonts are not embedded in your PDF, and there are several possible root causes...

The main root cause might be the usage of MiKTeX installed "for all users" (see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/393).

Additionally, it could be that you only miss some font packages that include Ghostscript's free fonts, **especially `symbol`** (see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112) - yielding non-embedded fonts in your PDF, and hence different behavior in different viewers.

I recommend you install all these packages: `bookman`, `courier`, `avantgar`, `helvetic`, `palatino`, `ncntrsbk`, `times`, `symbol`, `zapfchan` and `zapfding`; and then try again.

Comment: I solved this error by installing the only package I didn't have from that list: symbol. After installing and restarting the texstudio, I couldn't see neither the greek letters, but this was because the image was not being created again in pdf. Remove the image in pdf and run it again! :) Ps. Thanks ivankokan, you gave me the idea by reading you in that github post!

Answer (score 1):

(Not a real answer, just narrowing down what could go wrong, since I have MATLAB.)

I made EPS files in MATLAB 2014b on OS X and 2014a on Windows with the following

```
t=linspace(0,1,10);
x=sin(2*pi*t);
plot(t,x);
xlabel('\mu');
ylabel('\phi');
print -depsc2 greek.eps
```

and made a greek-mac.eps and a greek-win.eps. In MacTeX 2014 and TeX Live 2014 (Windows), the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{greek-mac} \caption{Mac EPS}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{greek-win} \caption{Windows EPS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

creates two figures on the page as expected, with Greek letters intact. So there's something more complicated going on.

Comment: Hello second Mike, one thing you post reminded me of is that I'm working in the 'elsarticle' document class. I don't know whether the good folk at Elsevier have written something into their document class which could clash with either the 'epstopdf' or 'includegraphics' packages, specifically with the interpretation of special characters.

Comment: It's possible (some publishers have *very* outdated templates, or templates that simply never considered use cases beyond their core standard packages). If your graphics work with my MWE but not with an `elsarticle` MWE, then that's a very important point to add to your original question.

Comment: Also, the `epstopdf` package isn't explicitly required in my case. That may be different with `elsarticle`. See if it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the symbol fonts changing when inserting EPS files made in Matlab into a LaTeX file. However, I only have this problem when I view my PDF output in the built-in PDF viewer of Texmaker. When I open my compiled report in Acrobat Reader instead, the fonts do display correctly. So I concluded it is a semi-problem.

You could check if you find the same result when opening in Acrobat Reader instead. Good luck with your work!