# Why does texmaker not display fonts from eps images properly?

Tags: fonts, texmaker, eps, epstopdf, embedding

When creating a pdf file including eps images and using texmaker, some of the characters from this image do not display properly.

Here is an MWE :

Create a file named `mwe.eps` :

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 828 552
%%EndComments
/Symbol findfont
106 scalefont
setfont
0 100 moveto
(\155) show
showpage
%%EOF
```

Now create a file named `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[5pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=165.6pt]{mwe.eps}%
\end{document}
```

Compile it and view it using texmaker, the image displays some sort of alpha, where it should display a µ. 
Now, if you view it using an external program as adobe reader, you can read the µ character just fine.

Why does it behave like that ? Im I doing something wrong ?

Comment: That is problem with the internal pdf viewer of TeXmaker.  I have my set up configured to use an external viewer.  Works fine with Adobe reader.   You are doing nothing wrong.   The TeXmaker viewer generally works fine with texmaker, however I would always recommend that you either carefully proof the printed document and/or view the final product from several other viewers, especially if the document is not going to be printed but just viewed.

Comment: It seems that this problem comes from the reader indeed. Is there a way to prevent it from happening then ?

Comment: @SamuelAlbert Have you checked my answer below?

Comment: @ivankokan I haden't seen your answer. Since my question dates from 2016, it's hard to know what the configuration was at the time. I just tested my mwe and despite the fact that the symbol package isn't installed, I couldn't reproduce the issue. So it's hard for me to tell if that would have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have `symbol` package installed. Therefore, Symbol font does not get embedded in PDF file, yielding different behavior in various viewers.

How to resolve the issue: install `symbol` package and try again.

Similar issue: [Loss of greek symbols in epstopdf conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225418/loss-of-greek-symbols-in-epstopdf-conversion)

Check this: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/112

Kind regards, Ivan