# Russian characters are absent when I put lilypond commands inside LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, lilypond

### Pure lilypond

Here is the lilypond file `file.ly`:

```
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
\relative{
  \omit Staff.Clef
  \omit Staff.TimeSignature
  \time 2/4
  c' _"Ч.1" c |
  c cs |
}
```

I compile it using this command:

```
lilypond --pdf file.ly
```

And get this:

[image]

The Russian character "Ч" is present.

### Lilypond inside LaTeX

LaTeX file `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
%the same code
\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
\relative{
  \omit Staff.Clef
  \omit Staff.TimeSignature
  \time 2/4
  c' _"Ч.1" c |
  c cs |
}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

Compilation commands:

```
lilypond-book --output=out-dir --pdf file.tex
cd out-dir
pdflatex file.tex
```

Output:

[image]

The Russian character "Ч" is absent.

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `pdflatex` (or, more specifically, `pdftex`) is the culprit. It seems `pdftex` [doesn't use the same font as lilypond does](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pdftex/5077). Here's the line from the pdflatex output:

```
[1 <./21/lily-98650107-1-eps-converted-to.pdf{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}>] (./test.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/ur
w/ncntrsbk/uncr8a.pfb

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/nc
ntrsbk/uncr8a.pfb): glyph `afii10041' undefined
```

It works without problems if you **compile the example by using `latex` -> DVI -> `dvipdf` -> PDF**:

```
lilypond-book --output=test test1.tex
cd test
latex test1.tex
dvipdf -dNOSAFER test1.dvi
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to compile lillypond files to small pdf. Cause when I compile my lilypond file it generated a huge A4 page. Like `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`?

Comment: In this case I would be able to compile them separately and import into the big doc.

Comment: Hmm - did you try to use `latex` and `dvipdf` (instead of `pdflatex`) to generate the pdf?

Comment: Erm, it generated an error. Seems, something is wrong with file: (/usr/local/lilypond/usr/share/lilypond/current/fonts/otf/CenturySchL-Roma.otf)

Comment: The file exists, probably it is unable to interpret it?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: is it possible to put it into chat? It's too big for comments. I am sitting here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: @user4035 You can compile the Lilypond file and then crop it to a minimal size before including it in the TeX document. See my script for doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174628/can-lilypond-produce-variable-paper-height-output/32281128#32281128

Answer (score 4):

While looking into this problem, I ran across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex/50834#50834) that seems to resolve the issue.  The short answer is to add

```
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
```

to your TeX document preamble.  I tested your MWE on my machine, and it seemed to do the trick using just `lilypond-book` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: This also works, but the same LaTeX file is compiled into 44381 bytes pdf through dvi and to 150531 bytes pdf using your command. 3,39 times bigger.

Comment: @user4035 larger file size is a risk with this workaround, as the same font can be included several times.  Some `lilypond-book` users may prefer the 2-step method over a 3-step method and not care much about the size.