# How to make sure that the PDF file has NO unembedded font?

Tags: fonts, pdf, font-encodings, embedding

I know that one can easily see which fonts are embedded in a PDF.

However, the conference I am submitting to requires that **ALL** of the fonts should be embedded.

Acrobat DC shows me the fonts that are embedded (below), but how can I make sure that **no font is missing from the list**?

As far as I know, PDF makers like PDFLatex sometimes drop SOME popular fonts to save space, while embedding the rest. Any solution to check that? And if so, what's the fix?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In today's tex systems embedding is the default, and you need to actively disable it. If you do it, you can see it in the font list. E.g. here I forced helvetica to be not embedded and then it misses the "Eingebettete Untergruppe" keyword:

[image]

If I switch back to embedding it looks like this (now a clone is used for helvetica):

[image]

Comment: It can still happen even if you force PDF embedding. If you include a figure (PDF file) that has some unembedded fonts, I don't think any tex system will try to include those unembedded fonts from the figure into the final compilation. Actually, most of those unembedded fonts are from the figures that are generated by visualisation software that sometimes don't have the option of embedding fonts.

Comment: Can you include in the answer how to disable the embedding of fonts?

Comment: @PeterGrill I would strongly recommend against ever doing that. PDF only allowed this for the standard 14 fonts, and even for them the functionality was deprecated since PDF 1.5 (2003) and is has been removed in the current version PDF 2.0.

Comment: @PeterGrill I used `pdftex_ndl14.map`, but as Marcel wrote, this is not something one should do for a real document.

Comment: @Ali right, with images you can still get this problem (but not if you create the images with a current tex, then you can only get the problem that you need `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50834/2388).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: My pdfs are not meant for distribution, and are intended to be viewable only within a custom app.  I have a large number of indivdual pdfs and am looking for ways to reduced the size and eliminating embedded fonts would be one way to do that.