# Including pdf with pdfpages corrupts figures

Tags: pdfpages

I want to include [THIS PDF](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9566401) in my TEX file but for some reason the output is messed up. The figures in the PDF are corrupted(see the titles in attached figure).

[image]

To reproduce, run:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
My paper:
\includepdf[
    pages=-, 
    scale=0.9, 
    trim=0 15mm 0 5mm,
    clip, 
    pagecommand={}
]{p-refined}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: the pdf is not available for the public. Try `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1 ` in the preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Amazing, you weren't even able to reproduce the problem but even so, your solution worked. Feel free to answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Absolutely! Thanks!

Comment: Related: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50829/2417](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50829/2417)